# What is the difference between JMS client and JMS broker?

Tags: jms, mq

What is the basic difference between a JMS client and a JMS broker?

Comment: Are you asking about Active MQ specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good explanation comes from the JMS 2 specification itself in section 2.2. Keep in mind that it uses the term *provider* instead of *broker*.

> JMS Clients - These are the Java language programs that send and
> receive messages.
>
> ...
>
> JMS Provider - This is a messaging system that implements JMS in
> addition to the other administrative and control functionality required of
> a full featured messaging product.